# Distribution Upgrade window not showing

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, vmware

I started upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 LTS.
I proceeded a few steps, started downloading some packages, but then the Distribution Upgrade window disappeared.

I can still see its icon on the launcher, but when I click on it, it doesn't appear.

Note that I am working through VMware Workstation 12 Player, but I don't know if it's VMware's fault or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it moved off screen. Change your display settings to something smaller, then back to what they usually were at. This will probably move the window back on-screen.

If it is still downloading stuff (check a network manager), you can safely cancel it, or even just restart if you want.

If it is using a lot of CPU, it is probably installing the packages, don't cancel here. If it seems to have idled, it is probably waiting for some user input during the installation. While not ideal, it would be safer to cancel or halt the installation mid-way here if necessary.

Comment: The screen resolution trick didn't help. It had a low CPU usage, so I cancelled it. Thanks though!

Comment: It was worth a shot. Hope your installation isn't broken now!